# The specified key does not exist - While copying S3 object from one bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy a S3 object from one bucket to another and the response is looks like this -

```
object(stdClass)#24 (3) { 
          ["error"]=> array(2) { 
              ["code"]=> string(9)
               "NoSuchKey" ["message"]=> string(33)
                "The specified key does not exist." 
       }
          ["code"]=> int(404) ["headers"]=> array(1) {
      ["type"]=> string(15) "application/xml"
    } 
 }
```

Here is how the code looks -

```
var_dump($this->s3->copyObject('bucket_1','bucket_1/'. images/1.jpg, 'bucket_2', 'bucket_2/images')).die();
```

According to method signature of **copyObject** I would need to supply **Source object URI** and **Destination object URI**.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Finally I fixed it after few hours of looking into amazon docs.

Here is what S3 Object keys are -http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys

As S3 is a flat file system, the folders are includes in keys,

```
$this->s3->copyObject('bucket_1','images/1.jpg, 'bucket_2', 'images/copy_of_2.jpg');
```

ACL can also be passed as a fifth parameters.